# Software for easy detection and storing name of the process, that created file or folder?

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, process

Is there any program that can show me in Windows Explorer what process has created some folders or files? It would be great to see not only file name, size, modification date and etc. but also name of the process that created this file

Comment: This information isn't stored by the NTFS filesystem, if a process has a file open, then obviously you can identify that though.

Comment: Looks really strange that I do not found information about this problem in Google or here in existing questions. I have many folders on my PC, in AppData especially, and I can not say what program created them. Some folders appear out from nowhere, and when I do clean up of my filesystem all that I know — that they come two weeks ago...

Comment: What you describe really isn't a problem.  Documents created automatically by a program are normally in specific locations, in folders, which clearly indicate what program created it.  The information itself is not kept by NTFS so there isn't a tool to track this sort of information.  For all other user files they are created by the user, and they have file extensions, so what program created them are really entirely controlled by the user itself.